# Using Parameter in Sql Query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I'm learning C#. The code as I show it works, but I want to pass the name of the table "city" as a parameter (@paramTable for example). None of the code I've found on the internet worked. Any suggestion is welcome, thanks!

```
     public DataTable LoadGrid()
     {
        DataTable DTabla = new DataTable();

        string str = "SELECT * FROM  city WHERE ID < 10;";
        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(str, conexion);


        if (this.AbrirConexion())
        {

            try
            {

                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(comando);

                adapter.Fill(DTabla);

            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            this.CerrarConexion();
        }

        return DTabla;
    }
```

Comment: How and where would the variable come from?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya SqlParameters can't be used for the table name.

Comment: That's right I was little too quick to mark it as duplicate. Parameter can not be used for table name. I think in that case OP needs to use string concatenation.

Comment: As others have already pointed out, you cannot parameterize table names, or other identifiers; this is because doing this kind of thing in the first place is generally unnecessary outside of improperly designed databases, and generalized database management applications (like MySQL Workbench).